# Splice on copied array removes object from parent / master array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have what you may call a parent array, a master array. On page load, a `json_encoded` PHP array containing information about every user on the site is assigned to a JS variable - `var all_users = <?php echo $users;?>;`. A `console.log` of this array looks like this...

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
         user_id: "4"
         registered: "2015-02-15 12:54:34"
         ...etc
    1: Object
         user_id: "5"
         ...etc
```

In an external `.js` file I have a few event handlers for various filtering options. At the moment these filters work by sending an AJAX request to the server, querying the database, and then returning the data. This is great, but it's unnecessary to query the database every single time (there will only be around 50 records) hence changing my approach to the JS array.

My solution therefore was to start by copying the contents of `all_users` to a new variable, `display_users`, every time the function below is called (so that to reset `display_users` to contain all users). The purpose of this new variable is to then be able to remove any records that do not match the user's filters. So for example a search for `user_id = 4` would result in the second, third, fourth, ... objects being removed from `display_users`, leaving just those that match.

```
var display_users = [];

function update_users (type) {
    display_users = all_users;
    i = 0;

    $.each(all_users, function() {
        var user = this;
        $.each(user, function(k, v) {
            // show_admin_only is true or false
            if (show_admin_only) {
                // if the key is_admin has a value of 0 they are not an admin, remove them from the display users array
                if (k == 'is_admin' && v == 0) display_users.splice(i,1);
            }               
        });
        i++;
    });

    // pass the array through to a jQuery template
}
```

The problem, however, is that the splice is causing an error. The first time the function is ran all is great, however on the second time Chrome reports two warnings, `'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.` and `'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.`. After these errors, any future runs of that function results in the removal of records from **both** arrays, the master and the copy.

Given this, I'd guess that `display_users` is acting as a pointer to the master array, `all_users`, but then that wouldn't make much sense to me, and is why I'm now at a complete loss. A `console.log` of both arrays after `i = 0` outputs this...

```
Run 1
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Run 2
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

// for every run, -1 Object from BOTH arrays
```

I added a `console.log(user);` within `$.each(user, function(k, v) {` and it is during these second, third, ... runs that it begins to output hundreds of `Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}` as well as those expected, such as `Object {user_id: "4", registered_date: "2015-02-15 12:54:34" ... }`.

Has anyone any idea why this is happening? Sorry for the long post for what is probably a very simple fix...!

Comment: `display_users = all_users;` doesn't create a copy of the array. This only copies the reference included in `all_users` to `display_users` and therefore both variables point on the same array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is right here

```
 display_users = all_users;
```

It is not copying the array but creating one more reference to the same array. If you wish to copy the array you ca use [Array.slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) instead

```
 var display_users = all_users.slice(0);
```

Comment: Got you! I guessed it was acting as a pointer (how else could it remove from both) but my tired little brain didn't think to search "how to copy an array". Thanks for the answer, sorry for the question...!

Answer (score 5):

For duplication use:

```
display_users = all_users.slice();
```